# Protected base class member not accessible from derived class constructor parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes defined this way :

**Classes**

```
class A {
    A(A& a) { ... } // deep copy
    <dtor + methods>
protected:
    A(std::shared_ptr<AImpl>& pp) : p(pp) { /* empty */ }
    std::shared_ptr<AImpl> p; // the only member variable of A
}
```

```
class B : public A {
    explicit B(const A& a) : A(a.p) { /* empty */ } // KO
    // OR
    explicit B(const A& a) { p = a.p; } // KO
    // OR
    explicit B(const A& a) : p(a.p) { /* empty */ } // obviously KO
    <members, ...>
}
```

**Note**:

`A(A& a)` is doing a deep copy of the object pointed by `p`, which is not what I need, so I implemented `A(std::shared_ptr<AImpl>&)` to initialize `A::p` with a **copy of the shared pointer itself** to share the ownership.

I cannot define a setter for `A::p` because `AImpl` must not be a public type and must remain in the scope of class `A` or its subclasses only (interface-implementation classes separation design).

**Issue**:

I have a compilation error with all constructor flavors mentioned above, saying that `p` is not accessible because it is protected in base class, but why?

Comment: `A(a.p)` ? You want to let `A::p` to be initialized from itself?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `A::p` not of the base of `B`, but of another object, when access is prohibited.

You could instead provide a protected constructor:

```
class A {
    A(A& a) { ... } // deep copy
    <dtor + methods>
protected:
    A(const A& a, int) : p(a.p) { /* empty */ }
    std::shared_ptr<AImpl> p; // the only member variable of A
};

class B : public A {
    explicit B(const A& a) : A(a,0) { /* empty */ }
    <members, ...>
};
```

Comment: My [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699a6ae7b6eaac87) with the very similar idea...